# How can use Github for my developer to work on my backend without having to share to much credentials and code?

Tags: github

I have a Node.js backend running on an EC2 Instance with a Mongo DB.

I need to make some changes to my iOS App along with the Backend. I have already shared the Frontend Source Code with the developer, but I don't want to share the backend (if I don't have to directly..)

I have come across Github but I am totally new to it - also I am not a developer myself.

How can I use it for my purpose? Also, can 2 developers - say iOS developer and android developer then work on the code at the same time, without causing any mess?

What would you suggest me to do?

Appreciate any help! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Android and iOS developer can work together it will not cause any issue.

Now coming to your question first of all why a frontend developer needs to look at the backend code?..

If it's necessary ask them particularly what they wants to know may be backend code documentation can help or if the guy just need a look at some specific thing you can use some remote softwares like TeamViewer or else you don't have any options he have to look at code you can use last option to ask him sign the NDA (Non Disclosure Agreement)

Comment: Thanks for the response! He is a full stack developer, thats why.
Yes, he has signed an NDA but I just want to avoid my code being all over the place - in my scenario, is it useful for me to use Github?

Also, I would like to change my Mongo DB password - whats the easiest way to do so? 

And one more general question, on my EC2 instance I have sent all incoming connection to my IP address - would it still be possible for an intruder to connect to my database, if he has my instance IP and my DB Username and Password?